# Create the Array from the given array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

My result array is

```
array(
    (int) 0 => array(
        'parent_id' => '3',
        'student_name' => null,
        'date' => '2014-07-16',
        'total_hrs' => '02:00',
        'subject_price' => '500'
    ),
    (int) 1 => array(
        'parent_id' => '3',
        'student_name' => null,
        'date' => '2014-07-16',
        'total_hrs' => '02:00',
        'subject_price' => '500'
    ),
    (int) 2 => array(
        'parent_id' => '4',
        'student_name' => null,
        'date' => '2014-07-17',
        'total_hrs' => '02:00',
        'subject_price' => '500'
    ),
    (int) 3 => array(
        'parent_id' => '3',
        'student_name' => null,
        'date' => '2014-07-23',
        'total_hrs' => '02:00',
        'subject_price' => '400'
    ),
    (int) 4 => array(
        'parent_id' => '3',
        'student_name' => null,
        'date' => '2014-07-23',
        'total_hrs' => '02:00',
        'subject_price' => '400'
    ),
    (int) 5 => array(
        'parent_id' => '3',
        'student_name' => null,
        'date' => '2014-08-04',
        'total_hrs' => '02:00',
        'subject_price' => '500'
    ),
    (int) 6 => array(
        'parent_id' => '4',
        'student_name' => null,
        'date' => '2014-08-04',
        'total_hrs' => '02:00',
        'subject_price' => '500'
    ),
    (int) 7 => array(
        'parent_id' => '3',
        'student_name' => null,
        'date' => '2014-08-11',
        'total_hrs' => '02:00',
        'subject_price' => '500'
    ),
    (int) 8 => array(
        'parent_id' => '4',
        'student_name' => null,
        'date' => '2014-08-11',
        'total_hrs' => '02:00',
        'subject_price' => '500'
    ),
    (int) 9 => array(
        'parent_id' => '3',
        'student_name' => null,
        'date' => '2014-08-18',
        'total_hrs' => '02:00',
        'subject_price' => '500'
    ),
    (int) 10 => array(
        'parent_id' => '4',
        'student_name' => null,
        'date' => '2014-08-18',
        'total_hrs' => '02:00',
        'subject_price' => '500'
    ),
    (int) 11 => array(
        'parent_id' => '3',
        'student_name' => null,
        'date' => '2014-08-25',
        'total_hrs' => '02:00',
        'subject_price' => '500'
    ),
    (int) 12 => array(
        'parent_id' => '4',
        'student_name' => null,
        'date' => '2014-08-25',
        'total_hrs' => '02:00',
        'subject_price' => '500'
    )
)
```

I want following result so that I will get the sum of "Subject Price" on the basis of parent id and month

```
array(
    '07-2014' => array(
        '3 (i.e Parent id)' => '1500 (i.e. sum of subject for parent 3 and month 07-2014)',
        '4 (i.e Parent id)' => '800 (i.e. sum of subject for parent 3 and month 07-2014)',
    ),
    '08-2014' => array(
        '3 (i.e Parent id)' => '2000 (i.e. sum of subject for parent 3 and month 07-2014)',
        '4 (i.e Parent id)' => '2000 (i.e. sum of subject for parent 3 and month 07-2014)',
    )
)
```

Following is the updated code

```
$sum = array();
    foreach ($array_push as $v) {
        if (!isset($sum[date('m-Y', strtotime($v['date']))])) {
            $sum[date('m-Y', strtotime($v['date']))] = array();
        }
        if (!isset($sum[date('m-Y', strtotime($v['date']))][$v['parent_id']])) {
            $sum[date('m-Y', strtotime($v['date']))][$v['parent_id']] = 0;
        }
        $sum[date('m-Y', strtotime($v['date']))][$v['subject_price']] += $v['subject_price'];
        $sum[date('m-Y', strtotime($v['date']))][$v['parent_id']]++;
    }
```

Result I am getting.

`array(
    '07-2014' => array(
        (int) 3 => (int) 4,
        (int) 500 => (int) 1500,
        (int) 4 => (int) 1,
        (int) 400 => (int) 800
    ),
    '08-2014' => array(
        (int) 3 => (int) 4,
        (int) 500 => (int) 4000,
        (int) 4 => (int) 4
    )
)`

Is there any way that I can have key as parent_id and sum of subject_price as value for that particular month.

Can you please suggest how can it be done. Your help will be appreciated. Let me know if you need any more information.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick (given $array is you input array) :

```
<?php
$array= array(...);
$sum = array();
foreach($array as $v){
    $d = explode('-', $v['date']);
    $d = $d[1].'-'.$d[0];
    if(!isset($sum[$d])) {
        $sum[$d] = array();
    }
    if(!isset($sum[$d][$v['parent_id']])) {
        $sum[$d][$v['parent_id']] = 0;
    }

    $sum[$d][$v['parent_id']] += $v['subject_price'];

}

var_export($sum);
```

To have all your "i.e. something" added, you can add this after :

```
$printable = array();
foreach($sum as $d => $g) {
    $printable[$d] = array();
    foreach($g as $p => $v) {
        $printable[$d][sprintf('%s (i.e Parent id)', $p)] = sprintf('%d (i.e. sum of subject for parent %s and month %s)', $v, $p, $d)
    }
}

var_export($printable);
```

Comment: Note that the indexes in output array should ignore day(s).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I edited my code. see response I am getting.

Comment: I edited it once again, following what you have added in your question.

Answer (score 1):

Try using a sql query like:

```
select attr1, attr2, sum(attr2) as sum from myTable group by attr1, attr2;
```

and then use it as wanted

Comment: Thanks for your comment. But, in my application it is not possible to do it using group by because I am seralizing the data so for that reason I am facing problem